# Unable to install package zoo

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to install `zoo` package using:

```
install.packages("zoo")
```

I am getting the following error:

> package ‘zoo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot remove prior installation of package ‘zoo’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpaa1iAI\downloaded_packages

Any assistance out there. Newbie in R

Comment: there is a prior installation of `zoo` package which it fails to remove. You can go to the folder where the library is installed (`.libPaths()`), and manually remove it

Comment: This error can occur when multiple instances of rstudio are open. If you have more than one rstudio windows open, try closing all but one.

Comment: thankx alot. it worked  perfectly on closing the other windows